# Tabs into a component not tab navigation

Tags: android, react-native, tabs

I have to set a lot of informations befor setting two tabs for more details, like this:
[image]

there is a tab component into a screen with other components.
how can I do it ? I don't think I can use tab navigation, there is a third party lib for that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this kind of screen using [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/en/).

You can use [createMaterialTopTabNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-top-tab-navigator.html#docsNav) for the tabs, and a custom header for the graph.